# TouchableOpacity and button not working in react native Modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created react native modal but TouchableOpacity and button doesn't get clicked when the user tries to click on it why so?

code: (part 1)

```
<Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
              <FilterScreen/>
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => 
                  this._setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                }>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
```

FilterScreen component:

```
return(
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity>
           <Text>Inside Filter screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)
```

In the above code, I have added FilterScreen component which has touchableOpacity inside it but when modal opens up I am not able to click on toucableopacity component it only displays it in modal but onClick not working.

Code: (part 2)

```
<Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
               <TouchableOpacity>
                 <Text>Inside Filter screen</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => 
                  this._setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                }>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
```

Above code runs if I add touchableOpacity inside Modal but same code inside filterscreen doesn't work by adding component why so?

Note: part 1 doesn't work but part 2 code works why so?

Comment: What do you mean "TouchableOpacity only displays and onclick is not working"? But you didn't define any. You only have it in TouchableHighlight and not in touchable opacity

Comment: @TyroHunter Part 1 code and part 2 code both are same with some minor change but in my case part 1 code doesn't work but part 2 code works why so ?

Answer (score 121):

My problem was that I imported the `TouchableOpacity` from the `react-native-gesture-handler` package, rather then the `default react-native` package. That was the package my auto-complete choose to resolve it to. After changing the import to the other package it worked again as intended.

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Thank you  ...but what is this gesture-handler package ?! It keeps apearing everywhere

Comment: react-native-gesture-handler came into my code when I followed the docs for introducting navigation between screens. It still lurks even though now I want to use modals instead of leaving the 'home' screen.

Comment: I could only get this to work by *using* the TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler, and *not* from react-native.  Nevertheless this answer pointed me in the right direction, upvoted

Comment: i just spend 1 hour smashing keyboard, then i found this...

Comment: lesson learned! never import similar named stuff from unintended packages. thank you very much

Comment: @DimaMalko lucky you! It wasn't just one hour for me @_@

Answer (score 3):

Try to rebuild project, if in process of development sometimes with reload app via enabled hot reloading, or reloading via command + r when modal open, can broke functionality, it was in my case.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using FilterScreen component as an inner Function try like this

```
renderFilterScreen = () => {
return(
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity>
           <Text>Inside Filter screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)
}
```

and in the code

```
 <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
              {this.renderFilterScreen()}
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => 
                  this._setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                }>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
```

if you are creating a separate component class  like `FilterScreen.js`, try like below

```
class FilterScreen extends React.Component {
 render = () => (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity>
           <Text>Inside Filter screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);
}

export default FilterScreen;
```

and in the Main class.

```
import FilterScreen from './ui/FilterScreen';
```

and use like you called in the part 1.

Comment: one of these method may resolve your issue, please check

Comment: your answer is not working. I am importing FilterScreen and using it inside Modal but TouchablOpacity is not working I cannot click on it.

Comment: do u handle any onPress logic in the code?, if not try console something on onPress, or try remove the parent <View> from FilterScreen , just in case, these are the ways , i used in my codes and works smoothly, please try and let me know

Answer (score 2):

I'm running RN 0.63.4 and the the only thing that worked for me was to use the new `Pressable` component instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have imported TouchableOpacity from react-native but it didn't work. I only get this work by importing TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler like this:

`import TouchableOpacity from 'react-native-gesture-handler'`

Reference link https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/

Answer (score 1):

My case was opposite too. It start to work when I use react-native-gesture-handler. So if you need TouchableOpacity in an animated modal(which uses gesture handler's PanGestureHandler probably) use it from react-native-gesture-handler.

Answer (score 0):

After no end of problems with React Native modals, I ended up creating this hook based modal library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@idiosync/react-native-modal

It doesn't use the additional native layer that the RN implementation uses, which seems to be the source of a lot of its problems

Answer (score 0):

In my case i resolve it with help useState, when i try open with static value, i can't press on button, but if i open modal with help of hook, work correct

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for your answer, but please read [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and improve its quality.

Answer (score 0):

seams to work fine on Ios but not for android use the new Pressable component instead. [see documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal)